# Converting a Color to and from a 6-bit color

Tags: c#, winforms, colors

I am trying to convert a byte (6-bit RGB) into an appropriate System.Drawing.Color structure. My byte looks like this:

```
 UNUSED
---------------------------------
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
---------------------------------
          R1  R2  G1  G2  B1  B2
```

So given this:

```
byte color = 51;
```

How do I convert this into the closest color match that I can pass into Color.FromArgb? I know there is probably some math formula involved in this, but I don't know what it is. I also need to go the other way around. I would need to convert a Color into a 6-bit byte. Please point me in the right direction for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would multiply by 85 rather than 64 so that 00 is mapped to 0 while 11 is mapped to 255.

```
Color.FromArgb(255, 85 * ((color >> 4) & 3), 85 * ((color >> 2) & 3), 85 * (color & 3))
```

Comment: I marked your answer as the correct one, since your 85 thing worked perfect. I upvoted itsme86's answer though because the rest of his formula worked great. I wish I could mark 2 answers as correct lol

Comment: I have this issue with SO as well. The 'best' answer is almost always a combination of 2 or more answers, so it's always hard to know what to do.

Answer (score 4):

You would just need to multiply your RGB values by 64.

```
int r = color >> 4;
int g = (color >> 2) & 0x3;
int b = color & 0x3;

Color frameworkColor = Color.FromArgb(r * 64, g * 64, b * 64);
```

And likewise, to go back to your 6-bit color:

```
int r = frameworkColor.R / 64;
int g = frameworkColor.G / 64;
int b = frameworkColor.B / 64;

int color = (r << 4) | (g << 2) | b;
```

Comment: Instead of 64, multiply/divide by 85 (255÷3) so that 110011b gets converted to FF00FFh.

Comment: I would multiply by 85, but, oddly, divide by 64. If you divide by 85, then only 255 would get mapped to 3, whereas you'd probably want other bytes (e.g. 254) to get mapped to 3 as well.

Comment: This is almost working, except when I have "00111111", its getting mapped to a Light Gray color. I want 00111111 to map to white, since all bits are on.

Comment: It's because you're using 64 rather than 85. 3 * 64 is only 192 rather than 255 which would give you white. Change the 64s in the first section of code to 85, but leave the 64s in the second section alone. It should be what you want.

Comment: @pbabcdefp -- Yep, that fixed it. Let me just try going back the other way now...From a Color to a 6-bit color.

Answer (score 3):

You would isloate the components:

```
int r = color >> 4;
int g = (color >> 2) & 3
int b = color & 3;
```

Then you can scale the 0..3 values to the 0..255 range by multiplying by 85:

```
Color c = Color.FromArgb(255, r * 85, g * 85, b * 85);
```

To go the other way you divide by 85 and put them together in a byte:

```
int r = c.R / 85;
int g = c.G / 85;
int b = c.B / 85;

byte color = (byte)((r << 4) + (g << 2) + b);
```